# How to Install block.io in your site?

Tags: api

how to install https://block.io/docs in your site? I have a running VPS and a domain now and seems pretty having a trouble regarding installing their API. Pardon me because I don't seem to get the tutorials in their documents. please someone enlighten me. thanks!

Comment: Which functionality are you wishing to install/use in your website ?

Comment: This question is unclear. You don't install an API, you use one. Is this about how to install a environment in which a software package runs (which seems more appropriate for stackoverflow), or about how to write code for that particular site's API (which is probably better answered in their support forums).

Comment: Pardon my question Pieter, yes I will their API but how do I implement it? I'm sorry I don't have much experience in the API's.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're asking. What are you trying to implement? What is your site's goal, and how do you need block.io for it? It's like asking "How do I install HTML?" when your goal is creating a blog.

Comment: never mind this Pieter I am moving forward and get how to install the block.io, sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [sign up on their website and get an API key](https://block.io/users/sign_up), then build and deploy web services on your VPS that interact with both your website and their API.

Comment: Hi will, I already have one and bought their $49 for 2k addresses, are you a freelance or a working guy? where can I message you privately? I need a teacher and if you need a payment, then please tell me. thanks!

Comment: @Pachupappy Hi, apologies, no, I don't have any bandwidth for this at the moment. That said, maybe you can figure it out. You can learn a lot by trying if you stay perseverant. :)